# come about vs happen - the difference?

Tags: difference

Let me put these verbs in the following sentences

1. Why did the Mahabharata happen ?
2. Why did the Mahabharata come about ?

Google doesn's show any results with 'come about' with reference to the above usage.

Could you please explain which on is correct and why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these is quite satisfactory. Both *happen* and *come about* may be used with events, and *come about* may be used with states, but neither is ordinarily used with works of literature or of another art.

> <sup>ok</sup>Why did World War I happen?  How did it happen that WW I started?
> <sup>ok</sup>How did it come about that Germany was defeated? How did peace come about?
>
> *BUT*
>
> ∗ Why did the Mahabharata happen? How did the Mahabharata come about?

So what you have to do to use these is recast your sentence to include an event:

> How did it {happen / come about} that the Mahabharata was written down?

---

∗ <sub>*marks an utterance as unacceptable*</sub>